# Spring Cloud Gateway with Kubernetes - Not able to find discovery-server-url

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, minikube, spring-cloud-gateway

Exploring Spring cloud gateway with minikube.

I'm struck when adding spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes dependecy to the pom.xml and getting the below error.

I have looked at the spring cloud gateway and kubernetes document, couldn't find reference to spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.discovery-server-url property.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiGatewayV2Application': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'client': Error creating bean with name 'compositeDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/composite/CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'compositeDiscoveryClient' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'kubernetesDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/discovery/KubernetesDiscoveryClientBlockingAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesDiscoveryClient]: Factory method 'kubernetesDiscoveryClient' threw exception with message: 'spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.discovery-server-url' must be specified and be a valid URL.
```

Current setup

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-gateway-v2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>api-gateway-v2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.2</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
       <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
       </dependency>

    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
             <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
             <type>pom</type>
             <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

ApiGatewayV2Application.java

```
@Slf4j
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiGatewayV2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayV2Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    DiscoveryClient client;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       log.info("Services: {}", client.getServices());
       Stream<ServiceInstance> s = client.getServices().stream().flatMap(service -> client.getInstances(service).stream());
       s.forEach(it -> log.info("Instance: url={}:{}, id={}, service={}", it.getHost(), it.getPort(), it.getInstanceId(), it.getServiceId()));
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 9762

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: after_route
          uri: http://foo-service:8080
          predicates:
            - Path=/football/**
        - id: after_route1
          uri: http://bar-service:8080
          predicates:
            - Path=/cricket/**
```

If I remove spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes dependency from the pom.xml, gateway starts without any issues and I can route the request to the backend pods successfully.  In this scenario, how does the discovery work?

For spring-cloud-gateway on AWS EKS/minikube, kubernetes dependency is not required?

Thanks.

Comment: You are mixing incompatible versions by setting the version to `1.1.10.RELEASE`. Can you say why you did that?

Comment: @spencergibb- I was following this link - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/spring-cloud-kubernetes.html

Looks like I need to use spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client.